# MU Domain mapping

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

I've installed the mu domain mapping, but i can't make it work. I have two different domains, one is point to the other domain (set up at mediatemple to point to the other domain's folder). That's working.

But when i use wordpress (not a simple php test), it's redirect to the primary domain. (I added the domain, set up cname primary.com.)

So: **www.secondary.com** redirects to **www.primary.com/secondary**.

P.s.: Using lastest WP 3.6; from a domain/server dummy

Comment: Have you setup your wordpress as a multisite? Do your hosting account have a dedicated IP?

Comment: The a-record of secondary.com should be pointing to primary.com's dedicated ip. If you're on shared hosting, mu domain mapping won't work. The free version is also sensitive to the wordpress version.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I didn't know i have to switch the domain individualy under site settings too, not just on network administration...